# How to add photo and video to JSON quiz format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am putting together a quiz with JSON, jQuery and JavaScript.

Here's my question in JSON:

```
"questions": [
        {             "q": "At a birthday party you counted 120 eyes. How many people were at the party?",
            "a": [
                {"option": "240",      "correct": false},
                {"option": "60",     "correct": true},
                {"option": "120",      "correct": false},
                {"option": "30",     "correct": false} // no comma here
            ],
```

How do I add an image to the question. Is this the right syntax?

```
I have a folder called img
“q”: "At a birthday party you counted 120 eyes. How many people were at the party? <br> <br>"  + 

"<i** src="/i**/eyes.filename\">,   ** denotes mg read: image source
```

Also, how can I embed a video file in the question which has a link in YouTube?

Comment: JSON has no knowledge of images or videos. You'll have to store it in a format that the receiver can understand and make use of. If you are the receiver, then make something up.

Comment: That's not helpful at all.

Comment: In what way is it not helpful? I'm telling you that there is no such thing as a ‘JSON syntax for images’. What else do you want to hear?

Comment: So, how can you add images or video to a quiz in js?

Comment: You'll have to invent your own format. Simply putting HTML in strings (as I think you're trying to show in your example) is a simple and flexible method. But whatever you choose, it's up to you to handle the format and do the right thing with it. JSON doesn't provide any magic.

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out. 
This is how you embed a video:

```
{ 
        "q": "How would you weigh on the moon compared to earth?",
        "a": [
            {"option": "More",    "correct": false},
            {"option": "The same",     "correct": false}, 
            {"option": "Less",     "correct": true}, 
            {"option": "Need more info",     "correct": false} // no comma here
        ],
        "correct": "<p><span>Good Job!</span> Eat your cheesy pizza, fries, nachos, and fly to the moon to be a size zero or watch this video <br> <center> <iframe width=560 height=315 src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/OIzOCvxJcSE frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe> </center> </p>",
        "incorrect": "<p><span>ERRRR!</span> Weight is determined by gravity, or how strongly gravity pulls on matter. Since the gravity on moon is weak compared to earth, you will weigh less.<br>Ready for a physics class? <center><iframe width=560 height=315 src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/OIzOCvxJcSE frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe> </center> </p>" // no comma here
    }
```

This is how you add an image in json:

```
{ 
            "q": "What is the amount of matter in an object called? <br> <img src=https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/composite/08,88/question-weighing-scale-vector-840888.jpg/>",
            "a": [
                {"option": "Weight",               "correct": false},
                {"option": "Density",   "correct": false},
                {"option": "Volume",               "correct": false},
                {"option": "Mass", "correct": true} // no comma here
            ],
            //Make it select any rather than all.
            "correct": "<p><span>Correct!</span> You like fancy words don't you?</p>",
            "incorrect": "<p><span>Fail.</span> Sorry. You need to brush up on your physics vocabulary. Weight is a measure of how strongly gravity pulls on that matter. Density describes how compact or concentrated something is, expressed as mass per unit volume. Volume is Volume is the amount of space that comprises a length, a width and a height, occupied by an object or a material.</p>" 
        }
```

Comment: Biffen, a lot of people are new to javascript like me. I was really hoping you could explain your answer with a sample code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse for your own benefit.

Comment: @patty_mnouchkine But… there's nothing to explain. Once again: JSON doesn't deal with images or video. You can put HTML in a JSON string, but JSON still doesn't know what it means. Which is why this answer doesn't answer anything. It could if you added the code that *uses* the JSON.